# How do I highlight dates in TCalendar

Tags: delphi

Sorry I'm quite new to coding. I have a button that gets a date from the user (TDateTimePicker). I want the selected date from the user to be highlighted a red colour in a TCalendar. How do I do this?

Comment: Try looking in the online help, e.g. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/Calendar_(Delphi).

Comment: There's no optional highlight by default. For that you have to advance a little bit. Your ultimate goal would be to override the `OnDrawCell` method of the calendar grid. [This](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)), [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Methods_(Delphi)), [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Modifying_an_existing_component_Index) and [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomDrawGrid.OnDrawCell) may prove to be useful.